# How to deploy laravel/vue application

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment

I developed an app in Laravel and Vue, I know that we run yarn run dev for Vue during the development process, now I want to make it live and I run the command yarn run prod. After that, I checked it on the browser and my Vue components are not rendering, is there anything else that should be done along with this.

Comment: did you test it localy or in server?

Comment: Look at https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir and make sure you configured Vue to output to a folder inside the Laravel public folder. Else your js files will not be found. Also you could use `pages` to let Vue create blade views during building. Make sure to read through the Vue documentation